# How to effectively deal with multiple entities in SQLite DB Android asynchronously

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask

I'm currently working on a project which requires is using Android and SQLite as the backend. I've looked on the internet and there are some examples where there are more than 1 table. However, I have normalized my db structure and have 25 tables to play with. What I have done is create a number of classes in an attempt to reduce the chaos in the code (the examples all seem to chuck their setup code into a single class, this is not very maintainable for my situation). All entities have a Schema (defines the table structure), model (defines what the object will look like) and a Dao (facilitates the data transfer by making the models from the associated table) For example, I have an entity called Project:

**ProjectSchema.java**

```
public class ProjectSchema implements Schema {

    public ProjectSchema() {
    }

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "PROJECT";

    public static final String COL_OWNERID = "USER_ID";
    public static final String COL_PROJID = "_PROJECT_ID"; // PK
    public static final String COL_PROJ_NAME = "PROJECT_NAME";
    public static final String COL_OWNER_NAME = "OWNER_NAME";
    public static final String COL_LOCATION_ID = "LOCATION_ID";
    public static final String COL_START_DATE = "START_DATE";

    @Override
    public String createTableQuery() {
        return "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (" +
            COL_PROJID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_PROJ_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_OWNERID + " TEXT, " +
            COL_OWNER_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COL_LOCATION_ID + " TEXT, " +
            COL_START_DATE + " INTEGER, " +
            ")";
    }

    @Override
    public String dropTableQuery() {
        return "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    }
}
```

**Project.java**

```
public class Project implements Model {

    private String projName;
    private long startDate;
    private String owner;
    private String userID;
    private String projectID; 
    private String locationId;

    //--- Constructors, and getters -- //
}
```

**ProjectDao.java**

```
public class ProjectDao implements Dao {

private static ProjectDao instance;

private ProjectDao() {

}

public static ProjectDao getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ProjectDao();
    }
    return instance;
}
@Override
public synchronized List<Model> findAll(Context context, String id) {
    return findAllProjectsyId(id);
}

@Override
public synchronized Model findOne(Context context, String id) {
    return getProjectFromId(id);
}

@Override
public synchronized void insert(Context context, Model model) {

}

@Override
public synchronized void update(Context context, Model model) {

}

@Override
public synchronized void delete(Context context, Model model) {

}
```

The main issue I am having is how to deal with lazy loading of these models from the database. Although there is asynctask, I don't think it plays well with screen rotations. However the current "best practise" is to to use a non-UI retained fragment instance to maintain the task as described by this blog http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html . However, I feel like this drastically increases the amount of code needed to be written, as I will have a task for each operation for each model. However, I am attempting to circumvent this by creating a DaoFactory which will return a specified Dao instance.

**DaoFactory.java**

```
public class DaoFactory {

public enum DaoFactoryEnum {
    PROJECTS, USERS
}

public DaoFactory() {
}

public Dao createDao(DaoFactoryEnum factoryConst){

    switch (factoryConst) {
        case PROJECTS : return ProjectDao.getInstance();
        case USERS : return UserDao.getInstance();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

**Dao.java**

```
public interface Dao {
    List<Model> findAll(Context context, String id);
    Model findOne(Context context, String id);
    void insert(Context context, Model model);
    void update(Context context, Model model);
    void delete(Context context, Model model);
}
```

However, in order to implement this, I feel like I am forced to make a non-UI fragment for each operation of a Dao (the callback methods within the activity is going to get hectic!) and marker interface called Model so that I can return them from the Asynctask. To me this feels very hacky and not maintainable. Are there any other possible ways to redesign this or use a library of some sort which has good support for screen rotations?

Further clarifications:
- I'm passing the Daos from the factory to the non-ui fragment, and doing the retrieving there.

Comment: I would suggest to use realm project. It seems to be easy-to-use for your case

Comment: Site https://realm.io

Comment: I had a look at realm, and it does look interesting. However, I believe it would have the same issue as previous. If I have an insert query which is fired off and does not complete before the activity can rotate, there is no way to tell the event to fire off again (without doing more hacks). Hence the reason for the non-ui fragment, since realm cannot pass objects between threads. In fact, in the realm github repo, they use realm within an asynctask. Unless, my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Just try it. Im sure they lost a lot of time to write good code for the same purpose

Comment: Why not, what have I got to lose... I'm just curious as to how to make apps bullet-proof when it comes to unexpected user interactions.